# Weak continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E=l^{p}$ and $F=l^{q}$ with $1<p<\infty$ with $1<q<\infty$. Let $a:R \to R$ be a continuous function such that
$$|a(t)|\leq C|t|^{\frac{p}{q}}$$
Given
$$x=(x_{1},x_{2},.....,x_{i},..)$$

set
$$Ax=(a(x_{1}),a(x_{2}),.....,a(x_{i}),..)$$

I proved that $Ax\in l^{q}$ and the map $x \to Ax$ is continuous from $l^{p}$ (strong) into $l^{q}$ (strong). Now I have to prove that if $(x_{n})$ is a sequence in $l^{p}$ such that $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$ in $\sigma(l^{p}, l^{p'})$ then
$Ax^{n} \rightharpoonup Ax$ in $σ(l^{q}, l^{q'})$. some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not special to $\ell^{p}$ spaces.  If $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces and $A: X \to Y$ is a  (strong-to-strong) continuous linear map then $A$ is weak-to-weak sequentially continuous.
Let $x_n \to x$ weakly in $x$. Let $g$ be a continuous linear functional on $Y$. Then $f=g\circ A$ is a continuous linear functional on $X$. Hence, $g\circ A (x_n) \to g\circ A (x)$. This is true for all $g$ so $Ax_n \to Ax$ weakly in $Y$.

Comment: That's cool, but the operator $A$ in the question is not linear (unless $a$ itself is identical to $0$ or linear in the case $p=q$).

Comment: @LMOTRU This answer is wrong since $A$ is not a linear map. Please cancel the approval so that I can delete my answer.